# Using "else if" instead of "else" when there is no other possibility

Tags: javascript

Recently, I saw an if/else block like this in Javascript - although the same question could apply to any imperative language

```
if (cond) {
  ....
} else if (!cond) {
  ....
}
```

Question: what is the purpose of `if (!cond)` after `else`?  If there is no other possibility, why shouldn't I just use `else` by itself?

My opinion is that the `if (!cond)` is redundant and should be eliminated, and I'm looking for pointers to documentation to substantiate that.

Comment: Your opinion is correct for this example. `else if` is used when there are more conditions beyond just `else`.

Comment: I see it all the time here on SO, and it's just wrong use, there's no need for `else if` to do the opposite of `if` as that's exactly what `else` does, but some people just don't get it right away.

Comment: As an alternative opinion, it can be done to make false improvement of code readability. Otherwise it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I'd suggest that either: there was initially another option that got refactored out, that another option is very likely in the near future (Some people dont do YAGNI), or maybe just badly written code. As you say, if theres no other option then whats the point

Comment: I thin the strongest argument against the `else if` is that it disguises intent.  No default `else` implies that it's possible for *neither* branch to fire.  If the intent is that exactly one branch always fires, the code should look that way.  There should be no edge case possible where both blocks are skipped.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the two conditions are the same (aside from the negation), that would simply seem to be (in my personal opinion) poorly written code.

Answer (score 1):

Still bad code, but maybe not that pointless:

```
var a = 1;
if(--a){
  el.innerHTML = 'here ' + a;
}else if(!(--a)){
  el.innerHTML += ', there ' + a;
}
```

Where obviously none of the el.innerHTML gets executed. Point is, readability aside, logically the structure is not redundant at all.

Comment: Good point that it's possible in some edge cases for none of the blocks may be executed.  I added a comment to my question to clarify.

Comment: @wrschneider99: I guess that depends on what you meant by `cond`. There's the expression and the value it returns. If `cond` was meant to represent the expression, then certainly there are a number of ways in which it could produce different results.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fringe case where this is different from if else, that is when the conditional is doing something. but its not a justification since it leads to hard to read code.

```
var silly = true;
function test() {
  silly = !silly;
  return silly;
}

if (test()) {
  console.log(silly);
} else if (!test()) {
  console.log(silly);
} else {
  console.log('silly')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well using `else if` in this fashion; it's essentially this:

```
if (cond)
{
    ....
}
else
{
    if (!cond)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

so yeah, completely pointless

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that either:

1. there was initially another option that got refactored out
2. that another option is very likely in the near future (Some people don't do YAGNI)
3. Maybe just badly written code.

As you say, if there's no other option in the statement then there not point to it

Answer (score 0):

the block

```
if (cond) {
  ....
} else if (!cond) {
  ....
}
```

means the exact same as

```
if (cond) {
  ....
} else {
  ....
}
```

the person who wrote the code you saw, most likely had more conditions within the if, and simply changed it to `else if(!cond)` while debugging things, instead of commenting it out and adding a `else` part.